# how to navigate to a panorama page in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

In my main page i try to navigate to another page(which is a panorama page) ,My c# code for mainpage is,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace Panoramatry
{
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        displsy();
    }
    public void display()
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GettingStarted.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
    }
  }
}
```

And my **GettingStarted.xaml** page has the following code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace Panoramatry
{
  public partial class GettingStarted : PhoneApplicationPage
  {
    public GettingStarted()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        display();
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        display();
    }
    public void display()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Navigation Success");
    }
  }
}
```

But while executing the navigation code in the mainpage i get the following error,

```
 An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Panoramatry.DLL but was not handled in user code
```

But when i use a button on main page, and add this navigation to its click event, then it works perfectly fine!
What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never heard of Panoramatry.DLL, what third party libraries do you have in your solution? Most importantly, which ones are referenced in GettingStarted.xaml?

Comment: @FunksMaName
No third patry libraries!!

Comment: Try two things, when you take off the display(); call, do you still have the same problem? if not, move the display into the OnNavigatedTo event block to see if the error is still being thrown                                                        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Navigation Success");
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

Comment: FYI Panoramatry is my project name!

Comment: Updated my question! please do have a look at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, Okay, now it's clearer

You can't use the NavigationService in a page constructor, it would not have been initialized . In the first page, where you do your navigation, move the redirect to the OnNavigatedTo event, e.g

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

 namespace Panoramatry
 {
   public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
   {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        display();
    }

   public void display()
   {
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GettingStarted.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
   }
  }
}
```

And by the way, a better way to handle conditional entry pages would be for you to use the UriMapping feature of wp. see an example [here](http://cdrussell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/wp7-uri-mapper.html) That way, you don't have an unnecessary page in your back button entry stack, providing a better UX for your users

Comment: when i use your code i get an error stating that,
Error 1 'Panoramatry.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NavigatingEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: I've update the answer, copy and paste it the way it is in the answer, it should definitely work, The last error you are reporting only occurs when the OnNavigatedTo is not spelt correctly or the signature is wrong.